# Maximum write speed of HP Ultrium 1760 drive

Tags: linux, sas, tapedrive, lto, lto-4

The write speed of the [HP Ultrium 1760 drive](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c01121300) is specified as 120MB/s with LTO-4 media and 80MB/s with LTO-3 media. However I get half of that - 80/40 MB/s respectively. The connector is SFF-8482 at the drive and SATA at the controller. The SFF-8482 technically supports 2 SAS lanes and there are cables SFF-8482 to 2x SATA (second photo). However I'm not sure if:

1. The drive supports 2 SAS lanes
2. If it'll work just pluggin a SFF-8482 to 2x SATA cabke in two of the ports of my controller
3. If it'll make any difference since the drive and controller are 3 GBit/s which theoretically is 300 MB/s and should be enough bandwidth to reach 120 MB/s actual read/write speed.
4. The SFF-8482 to 2x SATA are a bit rare - I found the one from the third photo on aliexpress. However i'm not sure if it'll fit phisically on the SAS controller. Probably not - the spacing ont he controller looks bigger.

I did try plugging it to windows and running some diagnostic tools from HP and it mentioned something like "the drive is not running to full speed."

- Controller LSI Logic SAS 3041E
- Cable used: the blue one from the first photo
- Tape drive: HP Ultrium 1760 drive
- CPU: an old Intel Core 2 Quad Q9400 @ 2.66GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- OS: CentOS 7
- Storage 4 disks in ZFS raidz (RAID-5), read speed: 230-350MB/s, write speed ~150MB/s (edited)
- cpu usage

**Update:** HDD speed is not the problem:

dd if=/dev/zero of=$TAPE bs=1M count=5000
5000+0 records in
5000+0 records out
5242880000 bytes (5.2 GB) copied, 67.8001 s, 77.3 MB/s

[image: SFF-8482 cable]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong page at HP (for the LTO-4 Ultrium 1840 drive). The correct link to the LTO-4 Ultrium 1760  drive specifications is:

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01386389

On the 1760 model page the sustained speed is 80MB/s uncompressed, 160MB/s with 2:1 compression.

Answer (score 1):

SAS runs at least 3 Gbit/s = 300 MB/s goodput. The drive is rated at 120 MB/s max (240 MB/s w/ 2:1 compression), so adding the second lane doesn't do anything.

Your SAS HBA uses SATA-style ports but they're totally fine for 3 Gbit/s.

Basically, your problem lies elsewhere.

- Are you writing an image or from file level? The latter can be *much* slower with small files than the theoretical sequential speed of your RAID group. Run a recursive copy against /dev/null and you'll see.
- The 3041E is a RAID controller, which might not handle a tape drive properly. Try a simple HBA or the 3041E in HBA mode, if supported.

Comment: I'm using one 800GB file generated from /dev/urandom for a test, not many small files. pv  to dev null shows 230-350MB/s. I'll check in settings for HBA mode.

Comment: The documentation mentions "LSI SAS 3041E SAS RAID HBA". I think that if I don't create any raid the devices are visible as physical devices (JBOD).

Comment: The difference is (might be) whether the card is in RAID or HBA mode, not whether a RAID group is currently defined.

Comment: I did not find anything in the setup about HBA mode

Comment: I think this controller is an mixed mode always controller. From what I found on the internet is that "HBA Mode: exposes physical drives to the operating system". If it wasn't in HBA mode I won't be able to see the drive itself. I think only smart array or similar controllers have these modes.

Comment: LSI docs are scarce in general, but "... install an LSI SAS 3041E Serial Attached SCSI (SAS) Redundant Arrayof Independent Disks (RAID) Host Bus Adapter (HBA) ..." http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01511148.pdf

Comment: Also I don't think the performance will be affected much by the current mode.

Comment: Oh, I have seen RAID controllers perform poorly or not at all with tape drives due to firmware, driver or settings issues.

Comment: That seams reasonable, but there is nothing I can do here, except try another controller. The firmware is the latest - that's the first thing I checked. Driver shouldn't be a problem since it's linux based on RHEL - if this is not stable I don't know what would be. And it's pretty common controller by a well known manufacturaer. I think it's HPE re-branded, so their quality standards should be high enough. Also that's not poor performance. Poor performance would vary and this is spot on 80MB/s.